# Eventarc trigger: filter based on PubSub message attributes

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, event-arc

I'm creating a Eventarc Trigger from a PubSub topic; I'm filtering on the Cloudevent attribute `type` (matching_criteria) but I would love to filter out events based on some of the **PubSub message attributes** . Is this possible?

If not, I'll have to do it in my code!

Comment: According to the first lines of this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter#:~:text=The%20Pub%2FSub%20service%20automatically,can%20have%20a%20different%20filter.) , messages can be filtered through the created subscriptions (which are created by default when an Eventarc is created) using attributes but not by the data in the messages.

Comment: @FahedSabellioglu thanks, this is interesting but it seems you cannot update the subscription filters, you can [only set when creating](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter#update_filter:~:text=You%20cannot%20update%20the%20filter%20for%20an%20existing%20subscription.%20Instead%2C%20follow%20this%20workaround.)

Comment: There's a Google Issue Tracker issue filled for this https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201040589